# Specifying double-sided typesetting in ConTeXt

Tags: page-numbering, context

When printing double-sided documents, I currently setup mirroring with `\setuppagenumbering[alternative=doublesided, location=]`. This seems odd, since the parameter is not solely about page numbers but rather page layout generally.

In the documentation, I found reference to both `\setuplayout[location=doublesided]` and `\setuplayout[location=duplex]`, but neither seems to affect how rights and lefts are handled. Is this intended behavior, or am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: `\setuppagenumbering[alternative=doublesided]` is the right way to get double sided documents. I don't know what was the rationale for including this in pagenumbering.

Comment: http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Layout#Defining_the_layout

Comment: Thanks @Aditya and @Henri-Menke. I saw the part about `\setuppagenumbering[alternative=doublesided]`, but I was hoping that the `\setuplayout[location=doublesided]` might also work. What does that latter command do then? I can't find any explanation in the documentation.

Comment: When you different page and paper sizes (e.g. `\setuppapersize[A5][A4]`) you can control the position of the page on the paper with `\setuplayout[location=...]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
\setuppagenumbering[alternative=doublesided]
```

is the documented way how to get a double sided page layout, see

- [Layout](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Layout) in the ConTeXt Wiki

  > [image]
- The <strike>[old](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/mp-cb-en.pdf)</strike><sup>1</sup> and the [new](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/ma-cb-en.pdf) beginner's manual

  > [image]
- The [ConTeXt reference manual](http://pmrb.free.fr/contextref.pdf) and the [old ConTeXt manual](http://pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/cont-enp.pdf)

  > [image]

---

<sup>1</sup> The old beginner's manual is not very specific about that.